# How to aggregate by grouping in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

Assume I have following tables

I'd like to grouping by`index` and then `sumup` scores.
and I want to add conditional sumup  `type=a`columns.

```
index type score
A      a   10 
A      b   10
A      c   20
B      a   30
B      a   40
```

My desired result is like below.

```
index  sum    sum(type=a) 
A       40      10
B       70      70
```

I'd like to add `sum(type=a)` columns in the following sql.

```
select sum(t.type) as sum,t.type as type

from yourtable t

group by type
```

Are there any way to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below - use `conditional` aggregation

```
select index,sum(score) as total_sum,
       sum(case when t.type='a' then score else 0 end) as sum_type_a
from yourtable t
group by index
```